# How to specify a search result page for a search box component which is in another site folder in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I am using sitecore 9.0.1 with sxa 1.7.We have a requirement where we keep common components in a shared site folder. We have added a search box component which is from a partial design of a shared site folder into our APAC site folder and we want to give a search result page for a search box component which is under APAC site but it is not showing the pages under APAC site. Can anyone please explain what needs to be configured here.

Below is the image of Tenant where the shared site is tagged

[image]

**Header is the partial design** where it has search box component in it and i want to specify the search result page here which is in APAC site

[image]

This is how search box component shows for search result page field

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: You need to select the search page item in the "Search Result Page" field in the control properties.

Comment: yes but the search result page is in APAC site folder .Search box component is in Shared site folder so its not showing the pages which is under APAC its showing as attached in the  scrnshot @RamanGupta

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your shared items included in the index they have to use a template which inherits from `_Searchable` (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable`).

In `\App_Config\Modules\SXA\z.Foundation.Overrides\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config` there is a computed indexfield defined that SXA uses for each item during indexing:

```
<field fieldName="searchable">Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.Searchable, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search</field>
```

One other thing to note is that if not specified explicitly search results will be narrowed to the current site. You can extend it adding additional nodes to `Associated Content` field, otherwise in the solr index the items will have `"searchable_b": false`

[image]

Comment: These things i have done but still i am not able to see APAC node to attach search result page in partial design of shared folder @Cristi Vulturar

Comment: Can you check if after rebuilding the sitecore index are you able to find the items in the solr index?

Comment: Yes i am able to see that.@Cristi Vulturar

Comment: I updated the answer to include the associated content update aswell. Can you verify if you have searchable:true in solr index after rebuild?

Comment: Associated content i have added already and can you please tell where to verify searchable:true @Cristi Vulturar

Comment: You can take a look at some examples here http://jitendrasoni.blogspot.com/2020/04/sxa-search-result-tips-for.html